# Highcharts remove theme background before printing

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a large Highstock chart, with the "gray" theme applied. Users can print this chart by pushing a custom button. What i want is to remove the theme's background gradiënt (or image?) before printing the chart, because we need to print the charts with a white background.

I think i need to remove the chart's background, print the chart, and reapply the background.

Does anybody know how to do this?

This is what i have so far:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#btnPrintChart", function (event) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        chart.backgroundColor = null; //not working
        chart.plotBackgroundImage = null; //not working
        chart.plotBackgroundColor = '#C0C0C0'; //not working
        chart.redraw();

        //Resize chart to fit paper
        chart.setSize(1000, 600, false);
        chart.print();
    });
```

Comment: I'm sure this answer will help you with backgroundcolor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429518/is-it-possible-to-change-background-color-of-highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately something like this is not supported. All you can do is to manipulate existing objects: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/3bQne/314/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        plotBackgroundImage: 'http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/skies.jpg',
        plotBackgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: [0, 0, 250, 500],
            stops: [
                [0, 'rgba(255, 255, 100, 1)'],
                [1, 'rgba(255, 255, 100, 0)']
            ]
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]
    }]
});

$("#b").click(function () {
    chart.plotBGImage.hide();
    chart.print();
    chart.plotBGImages.show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately not the answer i was hoping for, but thanks anyway!